# How to view your Facebook likes?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to view a history of all the status updates, blog posts, etc. that you've "Facebook liked"?

Answer (score 5):

You can quickly take a glance of your `ALL ACTIVITIES` since you joined Facebook by following the below steps.

1. Go to your Profile.
2. Click on Activity Log

[image]

Then you will be able to see your own activity log. You can search for specific month, etc just by playing around and by choosing the specific activity.

To learn more: https://www.facebook.com/help/activitylog

Answer (score 3):

Look on the [All Activity](http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=0000000000000/allactivity) page - from there you can see anything you have done at all since you joined Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean your own updates, there is your wall. But for other stuff that you have been liked, there is an activity panel, in your own page, that shows what you did. Almost everything you do will be posted on your wall, such as commenting, adding friends.